# Uncaught ReferenceError: someObject is not defined at ./node_modules/react-validation/build/form.js

Tags: reactjs

Uncaught ReferenceError: someObject is not defined
at ./node_modules/react-validation/build/form.js
at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:24:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
at ./src/components/Login.jsx (Hradmin.jsx:40:1)
at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:24:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
at ./src/App.js (bundle.js:21:75)
at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
i want the exact solution and how to prevent from this in future

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.